# Request authorization do not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use the following:

```
auth = request.authorization
if not auth or not metrites.check( auth.username, auth.password ):
    return metrites.authenticate()
```

and within module metrites i have:

```
def check( username, password ):
    # This function is called to check if a username/password combination is valid
    return username == 'nikos' and password == '*****'


def authenticate():
    # Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth
    return Response( 'Credentials of a registered user required!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="User!"'} )
```

But every time i type a user/pass combo it failes to accept it properly and is resking me.

Do i have something wrong?

Comment: Can someone help me? I'm trying this without request.authenticate and the logic and valeus returned are correct. Its when i add `auth = request.authorization` that it fails

Comment: I was able to solve this myself. Since i was using Flask under wsgi_mod i had to use this directive `WSGIPassAuthorization On` within my httpd-vhosts.conf